# Trying to use supabase in my flutter app and getting difference errors

Tags: android, flutter, dart, supabase

I'm trying to use supabase in my flutter application but unfortunately it isn't working , I created an account on the supabase site and initilized the supabase insinde the app with the code :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'MyUrl',
    anonKey: 'MyKey',
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
```

and I got this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app_links'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app_links:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.1.2/builder-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-1.8.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.0/bundletool-1.8.0.jar
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app_links' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app_links' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to change the

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
```

and the

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
```

and the error became :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\scr\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 912

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
      > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\Users\hazem\StudioProjects\test2\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

any ideas how can I solve it ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: I would try to upgrade your Flutter version and make sure you are also using the latest supabase_flutter SDK as well.